# Get SVG paths from SVG file?

Tags: java, html, svg, path

I want to know how I can get SVG paths from a SVG image file?

Comment: You cannot get the *original* svg from a png since a png is a raster image whereas svg is vector graphics. You can however us a tracer to convert raster graphics in some vector graphics image that looks *similar*...

Comment: Not really.  PNG is a bitmap format, not a vector format.

Comment: png is a raster format, svg is vector. Conversion is unlikely to give you anything that woul resemble what you'd get if you drew the shape in an SVG editor. Nevertheless there are lots of online converters available if you simply search for them.

Comment: @JoeC: that's what I say "**png is a raster image** whereas **svg is vector graphics**"...

Comment: How would I get paths from a SVG file then, I can change the format if that is the issue, updated question.

Comment: look for path elements.

Comment: An SVG file is just an XML file. Open the file in a text editor and you will be able to see the `<path>` elements. If you need to extract them automatically with a program, then any library that can read XML files will be able to do it.

Answer (score 4):

To get svg paths just open it with google chrome and watch in the inspect element html section